# Extracting information from Pandas dataframe column headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, header, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe with column headers, which contain information.  I want to loop through the column headers and use logical operations on each header to extract the columns with the relevant information that I have.

my df.columns command gives something like this:

```
['(param1:x)-(param2:y)-(param3:z1)',
'(param1:x)-(param2:y)-(param3:z2)',
'(param1:x)-(param2:y)-(param3:z3)']
```

I want to select only the columns, which contain (param3:z1) and (param3:z3).

Is this possible?

Comment: Try `df.columns.str.contains('param3:z1|param3:z3')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
df = df.filter(regex='z1|z3')
```

Comment: Hi NYC Coder, this has been successful on my sample data.  Tomorrow I shall try it on my full dataset and see if it works.  Many thanks.